# Ionic changing songs at background not working on IOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

My app is perfectly fine on android emulator, android physical device and ios simulator but when I tried to test it on ios physical device the change song is not working while on background and it throws me an error:

[image]

My AppDelegate.m

[image]

My background modes

[image]

Ionic Info:

[image]

My Dependencies

[image]

Comment: It will be better if you add the code directly.Actually I cannot see the pic you displayed...